# How to connect HTML form with Guzzle in PHP?

Tags: php, html, guzzle

```
<?php 
require '../vendor/autoload.php' ;
use GuzzleHttp\Client ;


$client= new Client();
$response= $client->request(
'GET',
'localhost:3000/persons/document.getElementById("findPersonByMobile").v
alue'
);

$body= $response->getBody();
$string= $body->getContents();
$json= json_decode($string);

document.getElementById("editPersonName").value = $json->name;
document.getElementById("editPersonAge").value = $json->age;
document.getElementById("editPersonGender").value = $json->gender;
document.getElementById("editPersonMobile").value = $json->mobile;
```

What I want to achieve is this: I have a form in which I enter a mobile number and then click on "Find". After that I need to send a "GET" request to my API at the given url.

Q-1: How do I enter form's value into the url?The way I have done it is wrong but the idea should be clear.

Then I have another form which will get filled with the response of the server. Again I want to ask how to fill the form's values from the received response.

I have written raw and wrong code just to highlight what I wish to accomplish.

Thanks.